# Show one div and close all the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, block, visibility, hidden

Lets say that I have 3 differentboxen:

```
<div id="1" class="box" style="visibility:visible"><p>Box 1</p></div>
<div id="2" class="box" style="visibility:hidden"><p>Box 2</p></div>
<div id="3" class="box" style="visibility:hidden"><p>Box 3</p></div>
```

How can I make a javascript with 3 different links that closes all the boxen (class=box) and views the box that i selected in the link (id="x")?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you: http://jsfiddle.net/UyTsm/

```
  (function($){
    $('.link').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('``.box').hide();
    $('#'+id).show();

   });

})(jQuery);
```